# Delete custom fields when deleting posts

Tags: custom-field

When I delete a bunch of posts their custom fields remain in the database, is there a way to remove them as well on deletion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the wp_delete_post function as follows:

```
wp_delete_post($post_id, true); //false (default) sends it to the trash
```

This function accounts for comments, term_relationships, posts.post_parent, and postmeta.

Comment: Thanks, why doesn't WordPress do that by default when I delete posts from the dashboard?